# Displaying two iFrames side by side

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to display two versions of a web page side by side using iFrames but i'm having some troubles with size and position attributes. (The left one seems to be displayed with a small height even though I set it to 100)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Split</title>
</head>
<body>

     <iframe src="link_v1" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"                           
                                    style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; 
                                                width: 49%; float: left; " height="100%" width="49%"
                                   align="left">
                                  </iframe>  

     <iframe src="link_v2" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"  
                                        style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;
                                        position: absolute;
                                        width: 49%; " height="100%" width="49%"                                 
                                         align="right">
                                        </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

size of your html is size of your first iframe

it is because you used `position: absolute` in second `iframe` it is outside html and body and hence it occupies whole height not the html height

have a look at codepen below

```
 <iframe src="link_v1" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"                           
                                style="height: 100%; 
                                            width: 49%; float: left; " height="100%" width="49%"
                               align="left">
                              </iframe>  

 <iframe src="link_v2" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"  
                                    style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;

                                    width: 49%; " height="100%" width="49%"                                 
                                     align="right">
                                    </iframe>
```

this way both of them will be inside `html` and `body`

also set height of `html` and `body` to `100%` make both iframes occupy full height

```
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

have a look at my codepen
http://codepen.io/war_lock1221/pen/XMzXWb

Comment: Consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a `position: absolute;` on your second Iframe, remove that and it works like the other.

Code:

```
<iframe src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2808637462/af65ad1f02516c07887ebc47bd51f8fd.jpeg" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"                           
                                    style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; 
                                                width: 49%; float: left; " height="100%" width="49%"
                                   align="left">
                                  </iframe>  

 <iframe src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2808637462/af65ad1f02516c07887ebc47bd51f8fd.jpeg" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"                           
                                    style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; 
                                                width: 49%; float: left; " height="100%" width="49%"
                                   align="left">
                                  </iframe>
```

I have created a JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5m5oy7fj/

Comment: thanks :) , but it seems that the web page still not fully loaded